# Auto update a field in mysql after some(in hour) time of record updation php trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am playing with one row only, so every time I will fire update query on my status field.
I have a table with status field in mySql.
As soon as someone update status to 1, I want that after 2 hour of that updation automatically it should be 0.

Comment: Try to achieve this by cronjobs.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56428

Comment: PHP is irrelevant, please don't tag it

Comment: trigger wont work in such case, you can create event scheduler in mysql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html.